# 19.10 says "upgrade to 20.04LTS?" Then doesn't

Tags: upgrade

I am running 19.10.

Ubuntu prompts me to upgrade. 
[image: I keep getting option to update to 20.04LTS from 19.10]

I click upgrade and wait. Nothing happens, even after several hours. 
I have tried **sudo do-release-upgrade -d**
and I get

> **Checking for a new Ubuntu release Upgrades to the development release are only  available from the latest supported release.**

Why can't I upgrade from 19.10?

Comment: have you tried to update from an other server,you can change it in settings in the picture you have posted.many servers lag behind in when they are updated.

Comment: I tried Duke server.  ....$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade  but I get KDE-STYLE-BREEZE not updated

Answer (score -1):

tried force update of kde-style-breeze,**sudo apt-get install kde-style-breeze** and then upgrade succeeded.  Thanks!